# Opening an Image object with an external application in C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing, system.diagnostics

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so bear with me. Here's my problem. I am loading an image as a byte array from database and storing it as an Image object called myImage.
This is fine and I know myImage is being loaded correctly because when I save it to disk I can open it without problems. However, in my application I do not need to save it, but rather
send it to an external application (such as Windows Image Viewer) to be displayed. This is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;

// Image that is loaded from the database
Image myImage;

// Fiew is my external image viewing program
Process fiew = new Process();
fiew.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Fiew.exe";
fiew.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\cube.tif";
fiew.Start();
```

I could, of course, save myImage to a temporary directory and pass it in as start info arguments. That works, but it is not an option for me.
Hence how can I substitute myImage for start info arguments so that it is passed to Fiew.exe instead of the image on disk? Is this even possible? Thank you for your time and help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of passing "a chunk of data" to launch a pic viewing application. I suggest you to find a workaround solution if there is no way to pass that much of data via command line start up method.

Comment: @JXITC I know it sounds strange, but I am hoping somebody would know a workaround or at least confirm that it is indeed impossible to do it.

Comment: you might want to read about interprocess communication: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @Gabriel GM Hmm, looks promising. Thanks, I will take a look at it right away.

Answer (score 0):

The `StartInfo.Arguments` is an array of strings, not binary data.

Also, it depends on what the executable will accept as start-up parameters.  Chances are, it is looking for a path to an image on the disk somewhere.

Comment: I realize I can't use StartInfo.Arguments for loading binary data. That is why I am looking for other methods, if they exist.

Comment: @statuskwo5 But aren't you at the mercy of what fiew.exe will accept as parameters?

Comment: That is true. When I tested it using StartInfo.Arguments as shown above it opened the image correctly. However, it would be nice if an entire Image object could be sent to it to be opened, but again I have no idea how to do it or if it's possible using a different technique.

Comment: @statuskwo5 You *might* be able to hack your way by putting the image on the clipboard and then manipulating the other program with SendKeys to paste it, but I highly doubt that's a good thing to pursue.